# C# LDAP DirectoryEntry query root entry

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, directoryentry

I am trying to pull some information from LDAP using the DirectoryEntry class in C# however I am getting an error when I try to query the ldap root.

The query I want to run is

```
LDAP://<IP>/CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=TestForest,DC=com
```

If I put that query into a tool like softerra ldap explorer it works and I get 2 results (I have an objectFilter=dnsZone)

[image]

I can get DirectoryEntry to give me results if I fully specify the DC root i.e.

```
LDAP://<IP>/DC=TestForest.com,CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=TestForest,DC=com
LDAP://<IP>/DC=RootDNSServers,CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=TestForest,DC=com
```

But ideally I don't want to have to do each root separately.

However if I try to run the query that works in LDAP explorer the error I get in C# is:

```
{"The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.\r\n"}
```

My full code is (args_root is the IP for the server, root is the queries from above) :

```
private static SearchResultCollection ldapSearch(String root, String queryString, String[] attributes, SearchScope search_scope, int pageSize)
        {

            if (args_debug)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Target: " + root);
                Console.WriteLine("Filter: " + queryString);

            }


            DirectoryEntry rootEntry = GetDirectoryEntryForRoot(args_root + " / " + root);

            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);

            if (args_referralhosts)
            {
                searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
            }

            if (searcher != null)
                searcher.SearchScope = search_scope;
            if (pageSize != -1)
                searcher.PageSize = pageSize;
            if (attributes != null)
            {
                foreach (string attrib in attributes)
                {
                    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(attrib);
                }
            }

            searcher.Filter = queryString;
            return searcher.FindAll();
        }

        private static DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntryForRoot(String root)
        {
            //Handle Auth here
            if (args_username != "")
                if (args_ssl)
                    return new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + root, args_username, args_password, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
                else
                    return new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + root, args_username, args_password);

            return new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + root);

        }
    enter code here
```

Comment: Are you running as Admin?  the tool is probably running under a different credentials  when running inside VS you do not get Admin privileges.  Running exe from outside VS will run with same privileged that is in your login.  To get VS to run as Admin you need to create a VS shortcut and then right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: No the credentials are passed into the application for the correct user to connect to AD.
I got it working changing the query slightly to remove CN=MicrosoftDNS and keep the (objectType=dnsZone) but its not quite what I wanted so leaving it open to see if there is a better way

Comment: I tested your method and it worked for me. What values are you calling `ldapSearch` with? And on which line does it throw an exception?

Comment: Thats strange then, it threw the error on the line return searcher.FindAll(); and the error was no search results returned. So the base "CN=MicrosoftDNS,DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=TestForest,DC=com" worked for you in C# to get data?

Comment: No, I used the DN of our domain. That's why I asked what values you used for all of the parameters.